# nested ORDER BY in SQL statement in LibreOffice Base

Tags: sql, nested, sql-order-by, libreoffice-base

In LibreOffice Base I want to, as reduced example, query the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT "ROWname"
    FROM "TABULARname"
    ORDER BY "ROWname"
);
```

The Error statement is:

> Cannot be in ORDER BY clause in statement [SELECT*FROM(SELECT"ROWname"
>   FROM "TABULARname" ORDER BY "ROWname")]

Without the outer query {`SELECT * FROM (…);`} it works. So what's the reason it can't be in an `ORDER BY` clause in that statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of HSQLDB 1.8 (the default Embedded DB in LibreOffice).  It makes the subquery, i.e. the stuff inside the outer () as a view and not a query, and it disallows ordering in it.  :-(

MariaDB and MySQL don't have this limitation.

Take the order clause out of the subquery and move it to your outer query if you can.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery returns an **unordered set**.  So specifying `order by` for a subquery is not allowed.  Only the outermost query can have an `order by`.

An exception is if you specify `limit N` in the same subquery as the `order by`.  The subquery will still return an unordered set, but the `order by` can be used to determine the top N rows.  For example:

```
SELECT  SUM(col1) as SumOfTop5Col1
FROM    (
        SELECT  col1
        FROM    YourTable
        ORDER BY
                col1 desc
        LIMIT   5
        ) SubQuery
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped understandig the error much. With the outer query I wanted to make a  SUM at the top X (e.g. 5) ordered results: `SELECT SUM("ROWname") AS "Alias" FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT "ROWname" FROM TABULARname ORDER BY "ROWname" DESC) LIMIT 5);` If I can add the `ORDER BY` only in the most outer query it will order the 5 (random) results. But I want to order first and then take the 5 top results. How do I manage that?

Comment: You can do that, but the `limit` should be in the same subquery as the `order by`.  Updated the answer, hope that helps!

Comment: Sadly I get the same error message: no `ORDER BY` allowed there. As you said it's an inner subquery still that tries to order …

Comment: Are you on MySQL?  Check `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: No, HSQLDB as mentioned by @eliptical-view.
That check returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT *
FROM TABULARname
ORDER BY ROWname
```